# Are electrons simple? Do they have any inner structure?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, elementary-particles, point-particles

The Planck length is far smaller than the classical electron radius. Could the electron have structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24001/

Comment: Also: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30134/ and very perhaps most of all http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34437/

Answer (score 2):

First I should say "we don't know".  The fact that an electron has an intrinsic magnetic moment (spin) suggests it probably has some structure though.

See [What is the mass density distribution of an electron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24001/what-is-the-mass-density-distribution-of-an-electron) for more on this subject.